# ¿Como utilizar el GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, layout, gridlayaout

Buen día, soy nuevo usando este gestor de diseños y tengo un problema necesito acomodar varios botones en un panel como lo muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya logre acomodar nueve de los diez botones solo me falta acomodar el numero 8 pero no lo he logrado. Intente hacerlo y logre que se pusiera en la posición que le corresponde pero no he logrado que abarque las dos filas (fila botón 9 y botón 10) solo abarca la fila del botón 9.Espero me puedan ayudar. Dejo la parte del código donde estoy realizando el armado:

```
public void armado() {
  ventana.add(panel ,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  if(shouldWeightX){
    cons.weightx=0.5;  
  }
  cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx=0;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot1, cons);

  cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.weightx =0.5;//Controla el largo del objeto
  cons.gridx=1;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot2, cons);

  cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.weightx=0.5;
  cons.gridx=2;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot3, cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.weightx =0.5;
  cons.gridx=3;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot4 ,cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =0;
  cons.gridwidth=4;
  cons.gridy=1;
  panel.add(bot5 , cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =0;
  cons.gridwidth=3;
  cons.gridy=2;
  panel.add(bot6 , cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =3;
  cons.gridwidth=1;
  cons.gridy=2;
  panel.add(bot7 , cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =0;
  cons.gridwidth=1;
  cons.gridy=3;
  panel.add(bot8, cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.ipady=0;
  cons.gridx=1;
  cons.gridwidth=3;
  cons.gridy=3;
  panel.add(bot9, cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx=1;
  cons.gridwidth=3;
  cons.gridy=4;
  panel.add(bot10, cons);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logras que se expanda con el atributo `GridBagConstrains.BOTH` y ademas de eso tienes que especificar el numero de celdas/filas con `gridheight`, en este caso son 2 filas para `bot8`, no necesitas repetir tantos `HORIZONTAL` para `cons` solo basta con una asignacion hasta que se necesite cambiar.

```
public void armado() {
  ventana.add(panel ,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  /*if(shouldWeightX){
    cons.weightx=0.5;  
  }*/
  cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx=0;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot1, cons);

  //cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.weightx =0.5;//Controla el largo del objeto
  cons.gridx=1;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot2, cons);

  //cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.weightx=0.5;
  cons.gridx=2;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot3, cons);

  //cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.weightx =0.5;
  cons.gridx=3;
  cons.gridy=0;
  panel.add(bot4 ,cons);

  //cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =0;
  cons.gridwidth=4;
  cons.gridy=1;
  panel.add(bot5 , cons);

  //cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =0;
  cons.gridwidth=3;
  cons.gridy=2;
  panel.add(bot6 , cons);

  //cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx =3;
  cons.gridwidth=1;
  cons.gridy=2;
  panel.add(bot7 , cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.BOTH;//Expansion vertical y horizontal
  cons.gridheight=2;//Numero de filas que llenara el boton
  cons.gridx =0;
  cons.gridwidth=1;
  cons.gridy=3;
  panel.add(bot8, cons);

  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;//Reset a relleno horizontal
  cons.gridheight=1;//Reponer el numero de filas a 1
  cons.ipady=0;
  cons.gridx=1;
  cons.gridwidth=3;
  cons.gridy=3;
  panel.add(bot9, cons);

  //cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  cons.gridx=1;
  cons.gridwidth=3;
  cons.gridy=4;
  panel.add(bot10, cons);
```

Esa rejilla acomoda los botones como se espera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias  JohnnyTB me sirvió tu respuesta  y  ademas por hacerme la corrección de quitar  cons.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; con eso entiendo que solamente son necesarios ponerlos cuando modifico el fill

Comment: Solo una pregunta mas que debo de agregar para que cuando agrande o achique la ventana los botones se ajusten al nuevo tamaño de la ventana

Comment: En que disposición? o mejor.... que todos los botones sigan ocupando el área entera del `JPanel`?